# How to make Bootstrap Carousel maintain image aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am using the out of the box carousel from the Bootstrap template and it works great, however, when I add an image and resize the browser window it does not maintain the image aspect ratio...rather it squishes the image horizontally.

Now I have tried many variations to maintain the image aspect ratio as the window is resized and the following code is the closest I've gotten. That being said, this code does maintain the aspect ratio but when the window is resized to a mobile phone size, the image height is basically 50px and you cant tell what the image is.

What I would like to have is for the carousel to behave like the one on this website when you resize the browser: http://teekay.com/

My current code:
Carousel:

```
<!-- carousel-->
    <div id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide">
      <!-- Indicators-->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div role="listbox" class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active"><img src="../images/carousel_resize_3.jpg" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive"/>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>text1</h1>
              <p></p>
              <p><a href="/login" role="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Sign up today</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item"><img src="../images/carousel_resize_1.jpg" alt="Second slide" class="second-slide"/>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>text2</h1>
              <p></p>
              <p><a href="#moreInfo" role="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item"><img src="../images/carousel_resize_2.jpg" alt="Third slide" class="third-slide"/>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>text3</h1>
              <p></p>
              <p><a href="#appInfo" role="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Browse jobs</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><a href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" class="left carousel-control"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next" class="right carousel-control"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.carousel-->
```

My CSS:

```
/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  /*height: 500px;*/
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  /*height: 500px;*/
  background-color: #777;
}
/*.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}*/
```

I have tried the answers in many Stack Overflow posts but I cant seem to get the carousel to shrink but also maintain the aspect ratio. What am I missing?

Thanks for the help!

### EDIT:

I managed to get it to maintain the aspect ratio with the following code, but now the carousel is not getting smaller as a whole when the browser is resized, any ideas how to do this?

```
/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

img {
    height: 500px;
    width: 1920px;
    /*object-fit: contain;*/
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Carousel images are responsive by default in latest Bootstrap 3 `{ display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto; }`. So, there is no need to add an `.img-responsive` class to your images. (Also, there is no need to wrap the `.carousel-caption` in a `.container`)

If you start with the sample markup [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) and **remove your extra style overrides**, you can see that the aspect ratio is properly maintained on different screen sizes. You can verify this using the same link above.

Comment: In Bootstrap v4 the aspect ratio is not maintained: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/